# Idiomatic clojure code in a markdown parser

Tags: parsing, clojure, markdown

Some time ago I [created a markdown parser in clojure](https://bitbucket.org/BigYellowCactus/mdclj) and I would like to get some feedback, since I'm a clojure noob in the first place (is the code understandable?/is it idiomatic?/can some things be improved?).

So I'm looking for feedback on best practices and design pattern usage (performance isn't my main concern).

The most relevant parts are:

**[blocks.clj](https://bitbucket.org/BigYellowCactus/mdclj/src/c89b27c80e1e843aa1fd11f9daa3e91807b5548d/src/mdclj/blocks.clj?at=master)**

```
(ns mdclj.blocks
  (:use [clojure.string :only [blank? split]]
        [mdclj.spans :only [parse-spans]]
        [mdclj.misc]))

(defn- collect-prefixed-lines [lines prefix]
  (when-let [[prefixed remaining] (partition-while #(startswith % prefix) lines)]
     [(map #(to-string (drop (count prefix) %)) prefixed) remaining]))

(defn- line-seperated [lines]
  (when-let [[par [r & rrest :as remaining]] (partition-while (complement blank?) lines)]
    (list par rrest)))

(declare parse-blocks)

(defn- create-block-map [type content & extra]
  (into {:type type :content content} extra))

(defn- clean-heading-string [line]
  (-> line (to-string)
           (clojure.string/trim) 
           (clojure.string/replace  #" #*$" "") ;; match space followed by any number of #s
           (clojure.string/trim)))

(defn match-heading [[head & remaining :as text]]
  (let [headings (map vector (range 1 6) (iterate #(str \# %) "#")) ;; ([1 "#"] [2 "##"] [3 "###"] ...) 
        [size rest] (some (fn [[index pattern]] 
                            (let [rest (startswith head pattern)]
                              (when (seq rest) 
                                [index rest]))) headings)]
    (when (not (nil? rest))
      [(create-block-map ::heading (parse-spans (clean-heading-string rest)) {:size size}) remaining])))

(defn- match-underline-heading [[caption underline & remaining :as text]]
  (let [current (set underline)
        marker [\- \=]
        markers (mapcat #(list #{\space %} #{%}) marker)]
    (when (and (some #(= % current) markers)
               (some #(startswith underline [%]) marker)
               (< (count (partition-by identity underline)) 3))
      [(create-block-map ::heading (parse-spans caption) remaining {:size 1}) remaining])))

(defn- match-horizontal-rule [[rule & remaining :as text]]
  (let [s (set rule)
        marker [\- \*]
        markers (mapcat #(list #{\space %} #{%}) marker)]
    (when (and (some #(= % s) markers)
               (> (some #(get (frequencies rule) %) marker) 2))
      [{:type ::hrule} remaining])))

(defn- match-codeblock [text]
  (when-let [[code remaining] (collect-prefixed-lines text "    ")]
    [(create-block-map ::codeblock code) remaining]))

(defn- match-blockquote [text]
  (when-let [[quote remaining] (collect-prefixed-lines text "> ")]
    [(create-block-map ::blockquote (parse-blocks quote)) remaining]))

(defn- match-paragraph [text]
  (when-let [[lines remaining] (line-seperated text)]
   [(create-block-map ::paragraph (parse-spans (clojure.string/join "\n" lines))) remaining]))

(defn- match-empty [[head & remaining :as text]]
  (when (and (blank? head) (seq remaining))
    (parse-blocks remaining)))

(def ^:private block-matcher  
  [match-heading 
   match-underline-heading
   match-horizontal-rule
   match-codeblock 
   match-blockquote
   match-paragraph 
   match-empty])

(defn- parse-blocks [lines]
  (lazy-seq
      (when-let [[result remaining] (some #(% lines) block-matcher)]
        (cons result (parse-blocks remaining)))))

(defn parse-text [text]
  (parse-blocks (seq (clojure.string/split-lines text))))
```

---

**[spans.clj](https://bitbucket.org/BigYellowCactus/mdclj/src/c89b27c80e1e843aa1fd11f9daa3e91807b5548d/src/mdclj/spans.clj?at=master)**

```
(ns mdclj.spans
  (:use [mdclj.misc]))

(def ^:private formatter 
  [["`"  ::inlinecode]
   ["**" ::strong]
   ["__" ::strong]
   ["*"  ::emphasis]
   ["_"  ::emphasis]])

(defn- apply-formatter [text [pattern spantype]]
   "Checks if text starts with the given pattern. If so, return the spantype, the text
    enclosed in the pattern, and the remaining text"
  (when-let [[body remaining] (delimited text pattern)]
      [spantype body remaining]))

(defn- get-spantype [text]
  (let [[spantype body remaining :as match] (some #(apply-formatter text %) formatter)]
    (if (some-every-pred startswith [body remaining] ["*" "_"]) 
       [spantype (-> body (vec) (conj (first remaining))) (rest remaining)]
       match)))

(defn- make-literal [acc]
  "Creates a literal span from the acc"
  {:type ::literal :content (to-string (reverse acc))})

(declare parse-spans)

(defn- span-emit [literal-text span]
  "Creates a vector containing a literal span created from literal-text and 'span' if literal-text, else 'span'"
  (if (seq literal-text)
    [(make-literal literal-text) span]  ;; if non-empty literal before next span
    [span]))

(defn- concat-spans [acc span remaining]
  (concat (span-emit acc span) (parse-spans [] remaining)))

(defn- parse-span-body
  ([body]
    (parse-span-body nil body))
  ([spantype body]
    (if (in? [::inlinecode ::image] spantype)
      (to-string body)
      (parse-spans [] body)))) ;; all spans except inlinecode and image can be nested

(defn- match-span [acc text] ;; matches ::inlinecode ::strong ::emphasis
  (when-let [[spantype body remaining :as match] (get-spantype text)] ;; get the first matching span
      (let [span {:type spantype :content (parse-span-body spantype body)}]
        (concat-spans acc span remaining))))

(defn- extract-link-title [text]
  (reduce #(clojure.string/replace % %2 "") (to-string text) [#"\"$" #"'$" #"^\"" #"^'"]))  

(defn- parse-link-text [linktext]
  (let [[link title] (clojure.string/split (to-string linktext) #" " 2)]
    (if (seq title)
      {:url link :title (extract-link-title title)}
      {:url link})))

(defn- match-link-impl [acc text type]
  (when-let [[linkbody remaining :as body] (bracketed text "[" "]")]
    (when-let [[linktext remaining :as link] (bracketed remaining "(" ")")]
      (concat-spans acc (into {:type type :content (parse-span-body type linkbody)} (parse-link-text linktext)) remaining))))

(defn- match-link [acc text]
  (match-link-impl acc text ::link))

(defn- match-inline-image [acc [exmark & remaining :as text]]
  (when (= exmark \!)
      (match-link-impl acc remaining ::image)))

(defn- match-break [acc text]
  (when-let [remaining (some #(startswith text %) ["  \n\r" "  \n" "  \r"])]                ;; match hard-breaks
    (concat-spans acc {:type ::hard-break} remaining)))

(defn- match-literal [acc [t & trest :as text]]
  (cond
    (seq trest)
      (parse-spans (cons t acc) trest) ;; accumulate literal body (unparsed text left)
    (seq text)
      (list (make-literal (cons t acc))))) ;; emit literal (at end of text: no trest left)

(def ^:private span-matcher  
  [match-span 
   match-link 
   match-inline-image
   match-break 
   match-literal])

(defn parse-spans
  ([text]
    (parse-spans [] text))
  ([acc text]
   (some #(% acc text) span-matcher)))
```

---

**[misc.clj](https://bitbucket.org/BigYellowCactus/mdclj/src/c89b27c80e1e843aa1fd11f9daa3e91807b5548d/src/mdclj/misc.clj?at=master)**

```
(ns mdclj.misc)

(defn in? 
  "true if seq contains elm"
  [seq elm]  
  (some #(= elm %) seq))

(defn startswith [coll prefix]
  "Checks if coll starts with prefix.
   If so, returns the rest of coll, otherwise nil"
  (let [[t & trest] coll
        [p & prest] prefix]
      (cond
        (and (= p t) ((some-fn seq) trest prest)) (recur trest prest)
        (= p t) '()
        (nil? prefix) coll)))

(defn partition-while
  ([f coll]
    (partition-while f [] coll))
  ([f acc [head & tail :as coll]]
    (cond
      (f head)
        (recur f (cons head acc) tail)
      (seq acc)
        (list (reverse acc) coll))))

(defn- bracketed-body [closing acc text]
  "Searches for the sequence 'closing' in text and returns a
   list containing the elements before and after it"
  (let [[t & trest] text
        r (startswith text closing)]
  (cond
    (not (nil? r)) (list (reverse acc) r)
    (seq text) (recur closing (cons t acc) trest))))

(defn bracketed [coll opening closing]
  "Checks if coll starts with opening and ends with closing.
   If so, returns a list of the elements between 'opening' and 'closing', and the
   remaining elements"
  (when-let [remaining (startswith coll opening)]
    (bracketed-body closing '() remaining)))

(defn delimited [coll pattern]
  "Checks if coll starts with pattern and also contains pattern.
   If so, returns a list of the elements between the pattern and the remaining elements"
  (bracketed coll pattern pattern))

(defn to-string [coll]
  "Takes a coll of chars and returns a string"
  (apply str coll))

(defn some-every-pred [f ands ors]
  "Builds a list of partial function predicates with function f and
   all values in ands and returns if any argument in ors fullfills
   all those predicates" 
  (let [preds (map #(partial f %) ands)]
    (some true? (map #((apply every-pred preds) %) ors))))
```

---

Some "highlights":

```
(def ^:private block-matcher  
  [match-heading 
   match-underline-heading
   match-horizontal-rule
   match-codeblock 
   match-blockquote
   match-paragraph 
   match-empty])

(defn- parse-blocks [lines]
  (lazy-seq
      (when-let [[result remaining] (some #(% lines) block-matcher)]
        (cons result (parse-blocks remaining)))))
```

This piece always seemed somewhat strange to me. Is using a list of function and `when-let` idiomatic here? Are there alternatives?

```
(defn- create-block-map [type content & extra]
  (into {:type type :content content} extra))
```

I'm using this function to create hashmaps in a certain "format". Is this an idiomatic approach?

---

P.S.: While looking at the code myself, I spot two minor things: I can use `when-not` instead of `when(not (...` and `clojure.string/join coll` instead of `(apply str coll)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is overall very impressive! Here are my thoughts:

It looks like you've pretty much written your parser "from scratch" -- you have it set up so that it takes text as an input and dissects it line by line, looking for blocks and spans, and labeling and converting them appropriately. This is great, but a much easier way to go about this would be to use a parsing library like [instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse). Using this approach, you define a simple grammar as either a string or a separate text file, and then use instaparse to turn it into a custom parser, then you just use the parser as a function on the text, returning a parse tree that contains all of the information you need, in either hiccup or enlive format. There's a little bit of a learning curve if you've never defined a grammar before, but I found it pretty easy to learn, and instaparse is one of the most intuitive parsing libraries out of the handful that I tried. I would recommend this method -- it lets you worry more about defining your grammar and leave the implementation details to instaparse. At this point you've already done most (all?) of the work manually, so you might want to stick with the structure you have in place, but you should at least consider re-doing it with a parsing library -- it would at least make it easier to add new Markdown features.

I think your `block-matcher`/`parse-blocks` section is elegant and idiomatic as far as I'm concerned. It's a nice demonstration of first-class functions in Clojure. The only thing is, I'm not sure that you need to wrap it in a `lazy-seq`, since don't you need to realize the entire sequence? I haven't looked super thoroughly at your code, but I'm assuming you would use this function to parse *all* the lines of text from the input, so this sequence might not necessarily need to be lazy. It all depends on how you're using that function, though.

I think your `create-block-map` function is nice and idiomatic, too. It's such a simple function that you could potentially do without it, and just have all of your `match-*` functions return something like this:

```
[{:type    ::heading
  :content (parse-spans (clean-heading-string rest))
  :size    size}
 remaining]
```

But you have so many different `match-*` functions, it would get tedious having that show up under every single one of them, so I think you did the right thing by pulling it out into a separate function, thereby enabling you to express the above as just, e.g., `(create-block-map ::heading (parse-spans (clean-heading-string rest)) {:size size}`. My only suggestion would be to consider renaming it to just `block-map` for the sake of simplicity -- that's just a minor aesthetic preference, though.

Lastly, I saw this bit in your `match-heading` function:

```
(when (not (nil? rest))
  [(create-block-map ...
```

You could simplify this to just:

```
(when rest
  [(create-block-map ...
```

Since you're only using `rest` in a boolean context (it's either nil or it's a non-nil value) within a `when` expression, you can just use the value of `rest` itself. If it's not `nil` or `false`, the rest of the expression will be returned, otherwise `nil` will be returned. The only reason you might not want to do it this way is if you still want the rest of the `when` expression to be returned if the value of `rest` is `false` -- i.e., literally anything but `nil`. If that's not a concern, though, `(when rest ...` is more concise and idiomatic.

Hope that helps. You're off to a great start!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've written the parser from scratch just to write a parser from scratch and to write some non-trivial clojure code for learning clojure :-)